# Presentation of SL$(2,\mathbb{Z}_p)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

We have a the presentation ${\rm SL}(2,3)=\langle x,y,z:x^3=y^3=z^2=xyz \rangle$. Can we do the same for SL$(n,\mathbb{Z}_p).$ I have seen the presentation of SL$(n,\mathbb{Z})$ [the presentation of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/786303/the-presentation-of-sl2-mathbbz).

> How can we give a presentation of SL$(2,\mathbb{Z}_p)?$

Comment: Isn't this just a repeat of [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3444969), which was answered by Dietrich Burde?

Comment: Or see [here](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/12/1/17/352398?redirectedFrom=PDF)

Comment: @DerekHolt Sorry sir i forgot, now I voted to close it.